# Number of ways so that at least one soldier find that soldier next to him is also selected.

Tags: permutations, combinations

20 soldiers are standing in a row and their captain want to send 7 out of them for a mission. In how many ways can captain select them such that at least one soldier find that soldier next to him is also selected.

How to approach this question? Could someone give me some hint?

Comment: "How to approach this question?" - Calculate total number of ways minus number of ways of the complementary case.

Answer (score 2):

Let us ask the related question: how many ways can seven be chosen from a row such that none of them are adjacent.

To count this, consider two cases: either the last person is selected or he isn't.

In the first case (*last person is selected*), among the first 19 people, think of it as sequences of six $Xo$'s and 7 $o$'s.  For example $Xo~o~o~o~Xo~o~Xo~Xo~o~o~o~Xo~Xo$ corresponds to the outcome that the first, sixth, ninth, sixteenth, eighteenth, (*and twentieth*) soldiers are all selected.

Convince yourself that the number of outcomes in the first case are equal to the number of sequences of $6$ $A$'s and $7$ $B$'s.  How many such sequences are there?

> $\binom{13}{6}$

For the second case (*the last person is not selected*), then among the first $20$ people, consider sequences of $\underline{~~~~~~~}$ $Xo$'s and $\underline{~~~~~~~}$ $o$'s

> $7$ copies of $Xo$ and $6$ copies of $o$.

Similarly convince yourself that you can count the number of outcomes in the second case by counting number of sequences of $A$'s and $B$'s.  There are then $\underline{~~~~~~~}$ outcomes in the second case

> $\binom{13}{7}$

Combining this information together, we have the total number of ways in which all selected soldiers *not* adjacent to any other soldier.

How many ways can we select seven soldiers if we don't care if any are standing together or not?

> $\binom{20}{7}$

How do you combine these two ideas to find the number of outcomes that you are interested in, counting how many ways we can select soldiers such that at least one selected soldier is standing next to another selected soldier?

(*what is the opposite of no selected soldier standing next to another selected soldier?*)

Answer (score 1):

*Hint $1$:*

> Ans $=$ (Total ways of selecting) $-$ (Ways of selecting with no two  adjacent)

*Hint $2$:*

> (Ways of selecting with no two  adjacent) $=$ (Ways of reinserting selections with no two adjacent)

*Hint $3$:*

> Reinsertions between the $13$ unchosen can be done at any $7$ of the uparrows

$\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow$